# Metodología para actualizar DB MySQL según cambios en su estructura DDL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

¿Cómo puedo actualizar una base de datos con el siguiente escenario?

Tengo una base de datos en un entorno de pruebas (servidor1) y debo actualizarla con la del entorno de desarrollo (servidor2), pero solo quiero hacer los cambios en la estructura, sin eliminar los datos ya almacenados, ya he revisado que:

No actualizaré la estructura de columnas existentes solo voy a agregar nuevas, y los datos que no existan serán colocados con un `default` o puestos como `null`.

Entonces, ¿cómo hacer la comparación del servidor de desarrollo y sacar las diferencia con respecto al servidor de producción y traer como resultado los cambios que debo efectuar el en servidor de producción?

Comment: Creo que debes aclarar mejor la pregunta, en la cual ni siquiera se entiende **cuál** de las dos ¿bases de datos o tablas? es la que quieres actualizar.

Comment: Castellano: Tengo una base de datos en un entorno de pruebas y debo actualizarla(aun no vez cual actualizare) con la del entorno de desarrollo,

Comment: @a-cedano no hace falta ofender, yo llevo poco y entiendo perfectamente el problema según lo expuesto por Francisco. Saludos

Comment: no hay ninguna ofensa hay una exclamación entre paracentesis para saber si el joven logra alcanzar ver el objetivo de la pregunta...

Comment: ¿Workbench no te sirve para eso? Y ejecutas la sincronización en el servidor de desarrollo y te muestra los scripts a ejecutar que son las diferencias.

Comment: no lo he visto ni probado tienes algún tutorial completo con esa operación?????

Comment: Revisa [esta herramienta](http://www.red-gate.com/products/mysql/mysql-compare/). Hace justo lo que deseas, comparar dos bases de datos y generar scripts con las diferencias detectadas. **Nota:** Hasta el día de hoy, no he encontrado alguna herramienta de este tipo que tenga la inteligencia para interpretar el orden de los cambios a efecutar, es decir, al generar el script con las diferencias lo debes revisar para saber si una sentencia no se ejecuta antes que otra, algo así como hacer un `ALTER` a un campo que no se ha creado (por ejemplo). Me cuentas cómo te va con la herramienta :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si no estas trabajando con [Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) te recomendaría usarlo, posee una funcionalidad que es la de sincronizar modelos.

**1. Ingenieria inversa**

Es necesario realizar primeramente la ingeniería inversa a tu base de datos de desarrollo que usando la herramienta resulta súper sencilla. Esto recupera en diseño tu base de datos.

El diseño se puede almacenar en un archivo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**2. Sincronización del modelo**

Después podes conectarte a tu servidor desde Workbench y realizas la sincronización.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posteriormente el programa te va a mostrar los scripts que resultan con diferencias entre tu modelo y la base de datos de producción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: agracias muy buena respuesta, esperare a si alguien tiene otros metodos para comparar y escojere el que mejor me trabaje saludos

Answer (score 2):

Existe un set de herramientas que se llama [`MySQL Utilities`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.6/en/), dentro del cual podemos encontrar [**`mysqldiff`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqldiff.html).

> Esta utilidad lee las definiciones de objetos y las compara usando un método `diff-like` para determinar si son iguales. La utilidad muestra las diferencias para los objetos que no son los mismos.

Supongamos las siguientes definiciones de objeto:

**prod_host**:

```
CREATE TABLE prod_db.table (num int, misc char(30));
```

**dev_host**

```
CREATE TABLE dev_db.table (num int, notes char(30), misc char(55));
```

Para generar un conjunto de instrucciones `SQL` que transforman la definición de `prod_db.table` en `dev_db.table`, utiliza este comando:

```
shell> mysqldiff --server1=root:pass@prod_host --server2=root:pass@dev_host --changes-for=server1 --difftype=sql  prod_db.table:dev_db.table

# server1 on prod_host: ... connected.
# server2 on dev_host: ... connected.
# Comparing prod_db.table to dev_db.table                         [FAIL]
# Transformation statements:

ALTER TABLE prod_db.table
  ADD COLUMN notes char(30) AFTER a,
  CHANGE COLUMN misc misc char(55);

  Compare failed. One or more differences found.
```

--

Un error común a intentar ejecutar este comando contra un servidor remoto compartido o dedicado, es el siguiente:

```
ERROR: Query failed. 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'USER'@'IP' for table 'proc'
```

Esto se debe a que `mysqldiff` intenta ejecutar `SELECT * FROM mysql.proc;`, y este comando esta bloqueado para todos los usuarios excepto para la cuenta `root`. Ademas hay que validar que el usuario `root` tenga privilegios para acceder de forma remota (eg: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD ...`).

Answer (score 0):

Si trabajas con Symfony + doctrine hay un bundle llamado **doctrinemigrationsbundle**t. Este tiene un comando Diff que te obtiene las diferencias de bbdd y el modelo que tengas definido, creandote un archivo PHP de migración.

En general, si utilizas un orm en tu aplicación para definir el squema suele haber una librería que te hace la diferencia del esquema según el entorno que utilices( dev, prod, test...)

Comment: estoy trabajando con php7 sin ningun framework osea puro ...

Comment: Plantéate usar alguno. La mayoría de esos problemas con bbdd ya están solucionados y aplicando diversas herramientas que vienen con ellos te ahorras problemas como el que tienes. Además te permitirá realizar integración continua, despliegues automatizados, controles de test (tdd...)

Comment: yo no tengo problemas con la base de datos simplemente no se que metodología utilizar para actualizar DB MySQL según cambios en su estructura DDL te aseguro que un framework me ayudaría si supiera como usarlo pero aprender a usar un framework a estas alturas de un proyecto avanzado me retrasaría completamente.